# How to get OkHttp3 redirected URL?

Tags: java, android, networking, okhttp

Is there a way to get the final URL of a request? I know that I can disable redirections and to this myself, but is there a way to get the current URL I'm loading? Like, if I requested a.com and got redirected to b.com, is there a way to get the name of the url b.com?

Answer (score 35, accepted):

The response object provides a chain of the requests and responses which were used to obtain it.

To obtain the final URL, call [`request()`](http://square.github.io/okhttp/3.x/okhttp/okhttp3/Response.html#request--) on the `Response` for the final `Request` which then provides the [`url()`](http://square.github.io/okhttp/3.x/okhttp/okhttp3/Request.html#url--) you desire.

You can follow the entire response chain by calling [`priorResponse()`](http://square.github.io/okhttp/3.x/okhttp/okhttp3/Response.html#priorResponse--) and looking at each `Response`'s associated `Request`.

Answer (score 5):

The OkHttp.Builder has NetworkInterceptor provided.Here is an example:

```
        OkHttpClient httpClient = new OkHttpClient.Builder()
            .addNetworkInterceptor(new Interceptor() {
                @Override
                public Response intercept(Chain chain) throws IOException {
                    System.out.println("url: " + chain.request().url());
                    return chain.proceed(chain.request());
                }
            })
            .build();
    System.out.println(httpClient.newCall(new Request.Builder().url("http://google.com").build()).execute());
```

[OkHttp3 wiki: Interceptors](https://github.com/square/okhttp/wiki/Interceptors)

Answer (score 3):

You can use "Location" from response header (see topic https://stackoverflow.com/a/41539846/9843623). Example:

```
{
{
    okHttpClient = new OkHttpClient.Builder()
        .addNetworkInterceptor(new LoggingInterceptor())
        .build();
}

private class LoggingInterceptor implements Interceptor {
    @Override public Response intercept(Chain chain) throws IOException {
        Request request = chain.request();
        Response response = chain.proceed(request);

        utils.log("LoggingInterceptor", "isRedirect=" + response.isRedirect());
        utils.log("LoggingInterceptor", "responseCode=" + response.code());
        utils.log("LoggingInterceptor", "redirectUri=" + response.header("Location"));

        return response;
    }
}
```