# OKHttp handle 302

Tags: java, android, okhttp, http-status-code-302

Every time I perform a OKHttp Post request on [this](https://hac.chicousd.org) site, the response code is 302 and the response body is:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Object moved</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <h2>Object moved to <a href="/GradebookSummary.aspx">here</a>.
       </h2>
    </body>
</html>
```

Here is my code:

```
OkHttpClient client = new OkHttpClient().newBuilder()
                            .followRedirects(false)
                            .followSslRedirects(false)
                            .build();
                    MediaType mediaType = MediaType.parse("application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
                    RequestBody body = RequestBody.create(mediaType, "checkCookiesEnabled=true&checkMobileDevice=false&checkStandaloneMode=false&checkTabletDevice=false&portalAccountUsername=username&portalAccountPassword=password");
                    Request request = new Request.Builder()
                            .url("https://hac.chicousd.org/LoginParent.aspx?page=GradebookSummary.aspx")
                            .post(body)
                            .addHeader("content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded")
                            .addHeader("cache-control", "no-cache")
                            .build();

                    Response response = client.newCall(request).execute();
```

My question is: How could I handle the response to be able to go to the new location?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All I needed to do was add a persistent cookie handler, which I found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35346473/6481734).

Answer (score 7):

OKhttp follows redirects by default but since you've explicitly disabled it in this case you'll need to check the `Location` header of the response to find the redirected url.

EDIT: You can get the new location via

```
String location = response.header('Location');
```

Comment: could you provide an example

Comment: Delete this: `.followRedirects(false)`

Comment: @JesseWilson I tried that, it gave me a page that said: you must enter a username and password

Comment: That means the page that you're trying to access requires authentication which is why you got redirected to the login page. Authenticate yourself first to access the page

Comment: I answered my own question, if you would like to edit your answer I will delete it and accept yours

Comment: It would be better if you elaborate on your own answer and accept it. Could prove to be helpful for someone referring to it later